Can I/Should I use a Chinese name?
I’ve been give a Chinese name which happens to sound like my American given name (Wesley).
Is there a way to have it appear here only instead of “WGroleau” without using a separate SE account?
And if so, would doing so give the (erroneous) impression that I am something more than a newbie?
For what it’s worth, “伟思礼” was suggested by someone raised in Beijing.
